# Memory and processing efficient multi-dimensional data structure C++

Tags: c++, performance, memory, multidimensional-array, data-structures

What is the best way to store multi-dimensional data in C++?
I am looking for some dynamic data structure rather than static multi-dimensional arrays, as the number of elements to be stored in the structure can not be pre-determined.

Additionally, I am looking for a data structure that can minimize the memory cost and provide faster lookup. Is there any ready made data structure or I must implement some multi-dimensional tree-based data structure?

Edit: I have to store multi-dimensional stream data in some data structure. E.g., the data stream is of the form: (key1, key2, key3, value1), (key1, key2, key3, value2), (key1, key2, key3, value3), ...

Later I would like to search the data with respect to different keys.

Comment: Fast for which operations? Insertions, deletions, lookups?

Comment: Get four people in the same room, and you'll get five definitions of what "best" means.

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." And I charitably chose this flag instead of _primarily opinion-based_.

Comment: @CoryKramer: Faster lookup

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I have provided the details of what best means in this question, in the second paragraph.

Comment: @shaikh: Interesting question, but any useful answer will have to be tailored to the actual data you have and the processing you want to apply.  As of now, only general advise can be given: the fastest algorithm is the one that doesn't run, the smallest storage size has the data that isn't stored. Memory locality is the primary concern for speed for almost all data/algorithm combos nowadays. For storage footprint, your trump cards are buying more memory, just-in-time calculation, redundancy elimination in that order. Custom allocators can improve multiple of these aspect, but are second order.

Comment: @peterchen: I have added more details to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to store multi-dimensional stream data in some data structure. E.g., the data stream is of the form: (key1, key2, key3, value), (key1, key2, key3, value), (key1, key2, key3, value), ...
>
> Later I would like to search the data with respect to different keys.

[`boost::multiindex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) allows to add different kinds of indices to your container.

It's a pretty complex library and can be a bit painful to get used to it. But that's worth the trouble, because the problem it solves is a pretty common one.

Comment: After studying the boost::multiindex, it seems that all the attributes of an element/structure must be indexed when using boost::multiindex.

Answer (score 1):

If the fast lookup and memory efficiency are the only things you need, consider using a hash table (for example, the STL one: `std::unordered_set<std::vector<int>>`).

This will allow you doing insertions, deletions and lookup in up to amortized `O(1)` time while consuming `O(n)` memory.

To use `std::unordered_set` we should provide a hash function, and `std::hash<std::vector<T>>` is not defined. The example of usage of this approach (including some not awful hash function) may be found [here](http://ideone.com/uoiKLy).

As @BiagioFesta mentioned, this code shows time complexity of `O(D)` where `D` is a number of dimensions, since each operation will calculate hash, which takes `O(D)` time. This may be accelerated by storing hash inside the element.

Comment: How it is multi-dimensional?

Comment: @shaikh Updated an answer. It allows you to put and find `std::vector<T>` which may represent multidimensional data. Unfortunately, it's not very clear from the question which operations you do need.

Comment: O(1)? I don't think so. The hash function is O(N), with N size of vector. Each operation will deal with the hash function, so in a strict sense the complexity is no constant (since " *I' am looking for some dynamic data structure rather than static multi-dimensional arrays, as the number of elements to be stored in the structure can not be pre-determined.* " -from question)

Comment: @BiagioFesta You right. Updated the answer